# XML-tag function

Tags: python, strings, xml

I'm an experienced programmer, but just a beginner in Python, and would like some input on a small function that's working but which I'm not very happy with.

It's used to produce XML tags (strings). The content argument can be a string, a number etc., but if it's a datetime I have to format it properly. Also, if there is no content, the tag should not be rendered (return empty string).

```
def tag(tagName, content):
  if isinstance(content, datetime):
    content = content.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
  else:
    content = str(content)

  if content:
    return "<" + tagName + ">" + content + "</" + tagName + ">"

  return ""
```

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return "<%s>%s</%s>" % (tagName, content, tagName)
```

e.g:

```
def tag(tagName, content):
  if isinstance(content, datetime):
    content = content.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
  else:
    content = str(content)

  if content:
    return "<%s>%s</%s>" % (tagName, content, tagName)

  return ""
```

Slightly more attractive if that's what you want?

Comment: Since there have been no other concrete suggestions actually answering the question I guess 1) there is nothing really wrong or non-idiomatic with my code, and 2) you deserve to get your answer accepted.

Comment: To be honest I think text based UI's are an ancient paradigm, but are mostly the best we have in terms of practicality for the moment. There are a whole array of approaches, node based UIs, wiki based UIs, social coding environments, batteries massively included libraries brimming with start convenience functions that might make logic / code elegance more obvious. Maybe it's offtopic or meandering but if you feel dissatisfied in general with the elegance - the problem isn't the language as such, it's the medium. It's steadily evolving.

Comment: Code Bubbles is one such thing I was thinking of: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsPX0nElJ0k

Answer (score 4):

Always use an XML library to read or write XML.
Stitching XML together with string concatenation misses the point of using XML.

Comment: If this simple function is all the XML functionality I need, I don't want to learn or take a dependency on a library. The question is not about that though, but would like to know if the function can be refactored into something more pretty.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking - how could it be simpler or more readable than it is now?  But if `content` may contain arbitrary strings, you're already producing invalid XML, so I'd focus on that problem first.

Comment: "how could it be simpler or more readable than it is now?" I don't know. It's what I'm asking. I know how to make it better in other languages. It feels like there should be better ways, and I'm just wondering if Python provides any nice features I could use here. (My real problem is that I think Python is ugly, and I want someone to show me that it can be beautiful after all. I'm still waiting (-: )

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of what you'd do in a different language.  I have no idea what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I'll criticise the general design of the `tag` function.

`tag` can't accept general input, because that would produce invalid xml. It special-cases empty contents, which prevents it from being generally useful; there is no way to use it to get an empty tag (breaking a weak requirement of good APIs: making simple things possible). It only makes sense as a private part of a slightly larger program that produces valid xml, which you did not include.

Comment: I totally agree. And it is a private part of a slightly larger program, pswinpy: https://github.com/tormaroe/pswinpy

Comment: Well that settles the type-safety question, unfavourably. `content` needs to be properly quoted.